# PHP and MYSQL: Convert 25 character long string to number

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am working on a project, were I need to store a 25 digit number. When I tried to use `BIGINT` data format, it shows **out of range**. Then I stored it using **VARCHAR** data type. But I also need to export this into an `MS-EXCEL` sheet.
When I export it, Excel show only 13-14 higher digits, the remaining lower ones are getting rounded off to which makes them **0's**.

My Source code is mentioned below:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dis");

$output='';

$sql= "SELECT `polid`, `inscompanyid`, polno FROM `policies` order by polid desc";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(!$res || mysqli_num_rows($res)){
    $output .='
        <table class="table" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>asdf</th>
                <th>qwer</th>
                <th>zcxv</th>
            </tr>
    '; 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $output.='
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["polid"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["inscompanyid"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["polno"].'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
    $output.='</table';
    //header("Content-Type: application/xls");
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: Prepend your large number with ' and Excel will display it as text

Comment: @TimWilliams your pre-pending worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

According to this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/when-i-am-entering-16-digit-number-in-excel-its/7f50828d-77b4-4ad2-8ea7-0411d0236bd0

MS excel does not like large numbers. It suggests that if you do not need to do any math on the numbers that you change the type of the cell to text (similar to the reasons you use varchar to store your number in mysql).

It's possible a workaround could be to output and download your file as a .csv and open in excel with text formatting for the columns.

Else, I think you should be able to be able to do this formatting with PHPExcel

Comment: Is not even displaying string properly. it is applying its formatting to that string as numbers.

Comment: If you open excel and then import the downloaded excel file and use text formatting for the excel columns, it still does not display properly? (sometimes if you open the file directly it will automatically apply formatting that cannot be corrected)